# Get rid of annoying logs by Firebase function "this may be a production service" & "External network resource requested"

Tags: firebase

When running a Firebase function, my logs are very noisy mostly because of those 2 messages

*Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  External network resource requested!*

I know I am running a production service, and yes I am requesting an external ressource  can I disable them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally using `--quiet` would silence this message, however because there are so many emulators, the Firebase team couldn't reach a consensus on whether to allow this to be silenced when used with `firebase emulators:start` (see [firebase-tools Issue #2859](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2859)).

The official stance on this is to set the logs filter to only show "user" logs using the [Emulator Suite UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/emulator-suite)'s Logs Viewer and let the regular log feed log everything.